# Find color on screen

Tags: python, image, colors, python-imaging-library

I'm currently trying to detect a color on a screen, for example a white pixel in a Black screen.
I'm grabbing the image with `ImageGrab.grab()` but I'm not able to search for the color. I tried:

```
 for x in range(0, 300):
            for y in range(0, 460):
                px = image.getpixel((x, y))
                if px[0] == 255 and px[1] == 255 and px[2] == 255:
                    print(x)
                    print(y)
```

but that didnt worked out for me. I saw something on with cv2, but he only showed a little bit of the code so i cant reproduce his code.
Thanks :)

Comment: Is your image converted to RGB before you loop through the pixels? Assuming you're using PIL, it would be something like this: ```image.convert('RGB')```, where image is your ```Image``` object.

Comment: Can you post the exact image you are loading, and include how you open it? Maybe it's related to that.